# Back and sidemenu issue in map form

Tags: codenameone

I've a map in a form. When I go back to another form, the white screen is shown. The white screen stays forever.As soon as back btn is clicked again or side menu btn is clicked, then only it goes back to the designated form twice. I've used revalidate in both forms as well. The back function works in all other forms except the one which has map component.

See the video with back issue [here.](https://youtu.be/4AQqyBxWKRM)

Home form

```
public final class Home extends Form {

    public Home(Resources res) {
        loadComponents(res);
        revalidate();
    }

    public void loadComponents(Resources res) {
        _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        _ _ _ _ _ _ _
    }
}
```

Form with map component

```
public class DealerLocation extends Form {

    public DealerLocation(Resources res) {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        //this is not working well while same code works in all the forms except in map
        Command back = new Command("") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                new Home(res).show();
            }
        };
        setBackCommand(back);

        SideMenu sm = new SideMenu(this, res);

        final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer();
                cnt.setCameraPosition(new Coord(lat, lng));
        cnt.addMarker(
                EncodedImage.createFromImage(markerImg2, false),
                new Coord(lat, lng),
                "Hi marker",
                "Optional long description",
                evt -> {
                    ToastBar.showMessage("You clicked the marker", FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE);
                }
        );
        cnt.zoom(new Coord(27.6743128, 85.3144726), 15);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, cnt);
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

SideMenu class

```
public class SideMenu {
    public SideMenu(Form f, Resources res) {
        FontImage homeIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, style, 3);
        Command home = new Command("  Home", homeIcon) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                new Home(res).show();
            }
        };
        f.addCommand(home);

        FontImage bookingIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_FILTER_NONE, style, 3);
        Command booking = new Command("  Book", bookingIcon) {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                new Booking(res).show();
            }
        };
        f.addCommand(booking);
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
    }
}
```

For the same code above, if I click side menu icon in the form with map component, then the app doesn't work well. It goes white screen and then side menu and all that again. Very poor performance.

See the video [here.](https://youtu.be/RxOeDAa1LT4)

PS. it works alright in simulator but gives these problems in android devices

Comment: Is this happening with a hello world Map demo and a side menu on your device? Is this happening on more than one Android device? What's the OS version/device?

Comment: I have checked it in samsung J7 prime (marshmallow) and nokia 5 (nougat). Both have same issue. For map demo, I haven't checked it. I'll msg u with the result for that soon.

Comment: Here is the test case. Have a look... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ATnICIY2S8ZG8xeE5tLWxHMXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this happening with a hello world map application?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. What is a hello world map application? While creating the app, I choose hello World (Bare bones). Is it what you are referring to? If there is a demo, please provide me the link.

Comment: I just tried a simple app that just adds a map and side menu command. I saw a bit of a flicker on my Android device but nothing else. Switching to the on-top-side menu improved things a bit but there seems to be an issue with the pointer event handling which we are looking at

Comment: In which devices did you test? Can you send me the apk file so that i'll test it in my devices? Have you looked at the test case I've provided. I did just the same as you have done and the problem exists. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ATnICIY2S8ZG8xeE5tLWxHMXc/view

Comment: One plus one with Android 6, this is my latest APK with the on-top sidemenu: http://codename-one.appspot.com/5270383258501120/98521e77-1b06-46ee-b171-8c29a1ef3484/NativeMapDemo-release.apk

Comment: I used the old side menu (not on top side menu). I am not using it since it doesn't go on top of status bar(looks a bit odd for now) . If you check, there might be problem in old hamburger menu. And in my device, the side menu sticks all the time, why doesn't it go away? https://youtu.be/dt2JrbB76Ks

Comment: That's an issue we have a fix for in git. It will be updated Friday. Here is a version without the on-top version, it flickers lightly for me http://codename-one.appspot.com/getData?m=result&i=5881041339547648&b=aa732a34-3411-42ca-8e19-e90d147f87fa&n=NativeMapDemo-release.apk

Comment: Can you share the project with old side menu so that I can compare it with mine. I had just used mapComponent nothing else. The side menu flashes a bit in your apk. My app is almost finish. So if the issue'll be solved in future,i'll keep it for now. And on top version is way sexier. I'd read the blog why it doesn't overlap the status bar but if you can work it out,it'll be so cool. I'm keeping it in all my future apps . Thankyou

Comment: The new version overlaps the status bar too, this was fixed recently, all I did was create a `MapComponent` instance and add it to the UI. Nothing else

Comment: thanks.. I used same code but now by making a new project and it works alright. My project is abt 2 months old and I've updated project libs from properties. It says your project libs are up to date. But the issue is not solved.Should I copy all the code and resources into new project or there is a way out? PS. I've updated cn1 plugin recently

Comment: Since the build happens on the servers the Codname One version isn't different. I'm guessing it's either a styling issues or a build hint issue. You can test it by copying the theme from your main project to the new project and seeing if the issue happens. Then trying to copy the build hints one by one until you can narrow down the offending setting...

Comment: No the old side menu doesnt work with maps. I forgot to add android.xapplication: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCuNx9BDs0Gh66Qv4vN28HyhTriIzODNSo"/> in the build hint. After it is added, the problem is seen again. And I tried using onTopSideMenu but the commands in the side menu are not working. The action listeners are not working

Comment: What's not working with the action listeners in the on-top side menu? Can you distill a test case and file an issue?